# images in bootstrap3 wont move to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i am making a website and I'm trying to get my images to be in the center or a little below but it just won't happen. Every time i try it stays at the t`enter code here

```
<img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings.com/wp-content/uploads/Question-mark.png?resize=512%2C350" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
<img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings.com/wp-content/uploads/Question-mark.png?resize=512%2C350" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
<img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings.com/wp-content/uploads/Question-mark.png?resize=512%2C350" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">



.image-thumbnail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #3B393E;
}
```

I dont understand what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap then in a div and use `text-align:center` to do the job:

```css
.image-thumbnail{transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); background-color: #3B393E;}

.myclass {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">

  <img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings.com/wp-content/uploads/Question-mark.png?resize=512%2C350" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings.com/wp-content/uploads/Question-mark.png?resize=512%2C350" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings.com/wp-content/uploads/Question-mark.png?resize=512%2C350" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add center class that build in on bootstrap

```
<div class="center">

  <img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings.com/wp-content/uploads/Question-mark.png?resize=512%2C350" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings.com/wp-content/uploads/Question-mark.png?resize=512%2C350" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings.com/wp-content/uploads/Question-mark.png?resize=512%2C350" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the selector that you use. The class name is `img-thumbnail` and u use `image-thumbnail`, what happened is you failed to target the element you want to select because of misspelled class name selector. Additionally, if you want it to vertically centered it needs the top position to be 50%.

```css
.img-thumbnail{position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); background-color: #3B393E;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings.com/wp-content/uploads/Question-mark.png?resize=512%2C350" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
      <img src="http://i2.wp.com/ajournalofmusicalthings
</body>
```